# What is the lifespan of a yogini, yakshini?

Tags: durga, kali, yakshas

As dakini/shakini are attendants of Ma Kali, and yogini also, for Devi (Durga)

In their own lok, yakshini are there too.

Just wondering what is the lifespan of these beings ? Thank you for any information.

Comment: In the usual sense - 500-1000 years, but I don't see much longer life than that.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Thanks, ok, that is what I’ve heard, but wasn’t sure if it was accurate. Could some live longer than that ? Due to good karma or siddhis or having vardaan etc

Comment: No one is ever born, nor they die. The atman is the true self. The body attached to it, in the form of ghosts, yakshas, etc is always temporary, usually mind-made. Human beings are made up of the physical body, which is even more temporary. The real self is even inside that - which is permanent and never dies and the one which is supreme god.

Comment: @User29449 Yes of course, thank you